# VSTS build schedule trigger when "Only scheduled builds if the source or definition has changed"

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have a build definition in VSTS, where the build triggers are scheduled with "Only schedule builds if the source or the definition has changed" checkbox selected.

The issue that we have noticed is that the schedule build is triggered when there is no change to either the build definition or the source code. The scheduled build is triggered even when there is a manually triggered build with the same source version.

Comment: I would say that is a bug. I recommend you to open an issue at https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as designed. It looks at the most recent successful scheduled build. Does not consider  manually queued builds here because they could have run with a different set of properties. [VSTS build Only schedule builds if the source or definition has changed](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/218545/vsts-build-only-schedule-builds-if-the-source-or-d.html)

Answer (score 0):

I submit a feedback here: [VSTS build Only schedule builds if the source](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/218545/vsts-build-only-schedule-builds-if-the-source-or-d.html) or definition has changed that you can vote.